# ¿Como crear base de datos o cluster en mongodb con node js?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Intento crear una app para empresas con la que un dueño de empresa se registre y al registrarse se cree una nueva base de datos en mongo db. estoy utilizando react para el front y nodejs para el backend. pero al buscar en la documentacion solo me aparece como crear los cluster manualmente ( estoy utilizando atlas para el service de mongo). pero no como crear un cluster nuevo desde codigo.

Comment: Claro, porque un *Cluster* de Atlas es un concepto de nivel superior al cual no tendrás acceso mediante una API o driver. No sé cuál es tu modelo de negocio, pero ¿no es una opción para tu aplicación crear simplemente una BD en el cluster que tengas ya contratado con Atlas? Porque lo de crear un *Cluster* por cliente no lo veo tan claro. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder, a lo que me refiero es que exactamente necesito crear una db cuando un cliente se registre pero al buscar en la documentacion me topo con como traer una db ya existente no como crearla en si ese es mi probleme jeje de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//mongodb por defecto busca base de datos ya creadas, si no la hay va a crear una con el nombre que tu le des, te dejo un ejemplo a continuacion:

//sencilla conexion a la base de datos

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongodb_uri = "mongodb://localhost/dbprueba"; //aqui es donde se creea la bd con el nombre que tu le des, en este caso sera 'dbprueba'

mongoose.connect(mongodb_uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true
})
  .then(db => console.log('conectado amongodb'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: Eso no lo sabia muchas gracias!